# Why/When to use realm.beginTransaction? Since there are executeTransaction and executeTransactionAsync

Tags: android, realm

For instance, if I have this pieces of code:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();
mUser.setName("Roy");
realm.commitTransaction();

textView1.setText(mUser.getName());
```

Based on the document, it says that the `Exception` will be caught and data won't be persisted if there is an error inside a transaction. So in above code, say if something wrong in `mUser.setName("Roy");` or `realm.commitTransaction();`, there won't be a crash and the code will still continue? However,`cancelTransaction` isn't called in this case. What will happen? **Update**: Looks like the app won't crash, but next time if you continue to read something from Realm it will crash and tell you that the Realm is locked, because commitTransaction is not called.

I just cant't figure out in what chances you will use `beginTransaction` and `commitTransaction` if there is a risk that errors might happen. There are alreay `executeTransaction` and `executeTransactionAsync` can handle it well. Especially with `executeTransactionAsync`, I guess most of you will use `executeTransactionAsync` as it has `onSuccess` and `onError`.

To me, I can only think of one reason: I want to just do a simple data update and still use the same thread, but in that case I will use below code instead, which is less error-prone.

```
try {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            mUser.setName("Roy");
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "error", e);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.error_occurred, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: One more thing is not mentioned by @EpicPandaForce in the answer, calling `executeTransaction` in a looper thread (like UI thread) will change all aync queries in that thread to sync queries. So if you are using sync queries in the UI thread, you'd better use the `executeTransactionAsync` in the UI thread as well.

Comment: @beeender well I didn't specify that because `begin/commitTransaction()` is also synchronous write transaction, which also turns async queries to sync.

Answer (score 9):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
       //...
    }
});
```

is equivalent to

```
realm.beginTransaction();
try {
    //...
    realm.commitTransaction();
} catch(Throwable e) {
    if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
    throw e;
}
```

So if you ask me, `begin/commit` is error-prone and you shouldn't use it without its `catch { cancel.. }` clause.

As for not calling `cancelTransaction()` in case of failure, I just ended up with cryptic issues that stopped happening once I started calling `cancelTransaction()`, but that was a while ago.

Comment: I can the exeption is thrown. So looks like a crash will happen if there is an error in the transaction. I still don't know who will use `realm.executeTransaction` or `realm.beginTransaction()` and `realm.commitTransaction()` as they are not really crash safe...

Comment: Execute automatically cancels the transaction. That is the point of it.

Comment: As my understanding of your answering, using "realm.executeTransaction" will prevent from app to crash, but its incorrect, in such when I try to create realmObject inside ".executeTransaction" improperly it will still lead to app crashing

Comment: Well you can't create an object that already exists, because it already exists.

Comment: im aware of that, but my point exactly, it should not crash the app when invalid code written inside a try { } catch ()

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand that ambiguity:

As EpicPandaForce said in the case "beginTransaction-commitTransaction" you can catch the exception and decide what to do with it, but in the case "executeTransaction" you can't - you can't say to above layer that error was happened.